# Can I use Dialogflow to answer a question that requires feedback from raspberry pi sensor?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Newb here to `dialogflow`. I have some basic intents working and returning hard coded responses. What I am struggling to understand is how to create a question that requires feedback from my Raspberry Pi and then telling Google assistant what to say.

Scenario

> User : Ok google, what is the temperature in the room?

I would like `dialogflow` to know this question and then have a call back to the Raspberry Pi which has the temp sensor on it. Execute code to read the temp and then tell Google assistant what that temp is so that Google assistant then says

> the temperature is __

Is `Dialogflow` the best way to achieve this? Would this be done with a webhook or should I be looking to catch this with `EventType.ON_DEVICE_ACTION` and then tell assistant what to say?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else needs information.

I was able to do this with Dialogflow and a webhook. On my raspberry pi I setup a node.js server and used http://serveo.net/ to get a public address. I placed that public address in the dialogflow web hook section.

My node api returns this json output and the assistant reads back the textToSpeech property. In the below json ???? would be replaced with value read from the sensor.

```
{
    "payload": {
        "google": {
            "expectUserResponse": false,
            "richResponse": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "simpleResponse": {
                            "textToSpeech": "The temperature based on your sensor is ???"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```